# I need help for a specific regular expression

Tags: php, regex

In my test there is following data

```
>0 Dollar</span
>0.01 Dollar</span
>0.00 Dollar</span 
>50.00 Dollar</span
```

My desire:

I want to differentiate dollar which is not 0.00 Dollar and 0 Dollar

Code that I am using

```
$str = $table['contents'];
$pattern = "/(Need help here)/";    
$a = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output should be an array whose value will be:

```
0.01 Dollar and 50.00 Dollar
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Please show your attempts to solve your problem instead of just `$pattern = "/(Need help here)/";`

Comment: If its actually html then don't use regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of DOMDocument and DOMXPath and use preg_match as a PhpFunction inside a xpath query.

In the example I have used `//span` which will get all the spans, but you can make the query more specific to your data.

```
$html = <<<HTML
<span>0 Dollar</span>
<span>0.01 Dollar</span>
<span>0.00 Dollar</span>
<span>50.00 Dollar</span>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xp->registerPHPFunctions('preg_match');
$pattern = '/\A(?=[0.]*[1-9])\d+(?:\.\d+)?+\h+Dollar\z/';
$spans = $xp->query("//span[php:functionString('preg_match', '$pattern', text())>0]");

foreach ($spans as $span) {
    echo $span->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
0.01 Dollar
50.00 Dollar
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/saAPi)

---

If you want to use a regex only, you could match the leading `>` and assert the trailing `<`. If the previous code example, `\A` and `z` are anchors that assert the start and the end of the string.

```
>\K(?=[0.]*[1-9])\d+(?:\.\d+)?+\h+Dollar(?=<)
```

The pattern matches:

- `>` Match literally
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `(?=[0.]*[1-9])` Positive lookahead, assert at least a digit 1-9 preceded by optional zeroes or dots
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?+` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\h+Dollar`
- `(?=<)` Positive lookahead, assert `<` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lt0aL6/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Onftr)

For example:

```
$data = <<<DATA
>0 Dollar</span
>0.01 Dollar</span
>0.00 Dollar</span 
>50.00 Dollar</span
DATA;
$regex = '/>\K(?=[0.]*[1-9])\d+(?:\.\d+)?+\h+Dollar(?=<)/';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
var_export($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
array (
  0 => '0.01 Dollar',
  1 => '50.00 Dollar',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [Lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), specially negative lookahead.

```
$pattern = '#\>((?!0\.00)[0-9\.]+\s+Dollar)\<#';
$a = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => >0.01 Dollar<
            [1] => >50.00 Dollar<
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.01 Dollar
            [1] => 50.00 Dollar
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work for 
>0 Dollar</span 
>0.00 Dollar</span 
>0.01 Dollar</span 
>50.00 Dollar</span

Comment: @AsifIqbal I posted my answer before your update on the post. your first edition of the post was not sharing the 0 Dollar